# SQL query returns multiple rows when trying to find specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables. One is called "Tasks" and the other one is called "TaskDescription"
in my "Task" the setup looks like this:
"taskID(primary)","FileID","TaskTypeID" and a bunch of other columns irrelevant.

Then in my "TaskDescription", the setup looks like:
"TaskTypeID", "TaskTypeDesc"

so for example if TaskTypeID is 1 , then the description would be"admin"
or if TaskTypeID is 2, then TaskTypeDesc would be "Employee" etc.

The two tables have a relationship on the primary/foreign key "TaskTypeID".

What I am trying to do is get a task id, and the TaskDesc where the FileID matches the @fileID(which I pass in as a param). However in my query I get multiple rows returned instead of a single row when trying to obtain the description.

this is my query:

```
SELECT taskid,
       ( 'Task ID: '
         + Cast(cf.taskid AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ' - '
         + Cast((SELECT DISTINCT td.tasktypedesc FROM casefiletaskdescriptions
         td JOIN
         casefiletasks cft ON td.tasktypeid=cft.tasktypeid WHERE cft.taskid =
         1841 )AS
         NVARCHAR(100))
         + ' - Investigator : ' + ( Cast(i.fname AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' '
                                    + Cast(i.lname AS NVARCHAR(20)) ) ) AS
       'Display'
FROM   casefiletasks [cf]
       JOIN investigators i
         ON CF.taskasgnto = i.investigatorid
WHERE  cf.fileid = 2011630988
       AND cf.concluded = 0
       AND cf.progressflag != 'Conclude'
```

I am trying to get the output to look like "Task ID: 1234 - Admin - Investigator : John Doe". However I am having trouble on this part:

```
CAST((select DISTINCT td.TaskTypeDesc from CaseFileTaskDescriptions td 
JOIN CaseFileTasks cft ON td.TaskTypeID=cft.TaskTypeID 
where cft.TaskID =1841 )as nvarchar(100))
```

This seems to work but the problem is I have to hard code the value "1841" to make it work. Is there a way to assign a "taskID" variable with the values being returned from the TaskID select query, or will it not work since I think sql runs everything at once instead of line by line.

EDIT-this is in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: yes sorry. I've added it in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *dynamically* reference a column that exists in your `FROM` set. In this case, it would be any column from `casefiletasks` or `investigators`. You would replace `1841` with the `table.column` reference.

[image]

**Update**

Replacing your static integer with the column reference, your query would look like:

```
SELECT taskid,
       ( 'Task ID: '
         + Cast(cf.taskid AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ' - '
         + Cast((SELECT DISTINCT td.tasktypedesc FROM casefiletaskdescriptions
         td JOIN
         casefiletasks cft ON td.tasktypeid=cft.tasktypeid WHERE cft.taskid =
         cf.taskid )AS
         NVARCHAR(100))
         + ' - Investigator : ' + ( Cast(i.fname AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' '
                                    + Cast(i.lname AS NVARCHAR(20)) ) ) AS
       'Display'
FROM   casefiletasks [cf]
       JOIN investigators i
         ON CF.taskasgnto = i.investigatorid
WHERE  cf.fileid = 2011630988
       AND cf.concluded = 0
       AND cf.progressflag != 'Conclude'
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you a little more specific? I've never heard of this. I was trying to compare it by TaskID since that works and only returns 1 row. How could I use this to check "Where cft.TaskID = ____"?

Comment: @john With sub-queries, you can reference a column that is from your outer set. This means that you would replace `1841` with the column name where it appears in `casefiletasks` or `investigators` from the outer set. Basically, what table does `taskid` come from?

Comment: EDIT: Thank you. I now see what you mean. I never knew this. But how can I stop the subquery from producing a second column? when the results are shown, it shows up as "TaskID" and "Display"?

Comment: @john See my edit. Just make sure to alias/prefix it (with the table name) to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The extra column doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work as your inner query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT td.TaskTypeDesc FROM CaseFileTaskDescriptions td 
JOIN CaseFileTasks cft ON td.TaskTypeID = cft.TaskTypeID 
WHERE cft.TaskID = cf.TaskID
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do another join instead of a subquery?

```
SELECT taskid,
       ( 'Task ID: '
         + Cast(cf.taskid AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ' - '
         + Cast(td.tasktypedesc AS NVARCHAR(100))
         + ' - Investigator : ' + ( Cast(i.fname AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' '
                                    + Cast(i.lname AS NVARCHAR(20)) ) ) AS
       'Display'
FROM   casefiletasks [cf]
       JOIN investigators i
         ON CF.taskasgnto = i.investigatorid
       JOIN casefiletaskdescriptions td
         ON td.tasktypeid = cf.tasktypeid
WHERE  cf.fileid = 2011630988
       AND cf.concluded = 0
       AND cf.progressflag != 'Conclude'
```

Comment: You know what, after I read your answer about just doing another join I felt like slapping myself....This works as well.